# how can i store the value returned by my init to be used in my functions

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have the init code and it returns me a structure

```
public any function init() {
    httpService = new http();
    httpService.setUrl("#Application.baseURL#security/oauth2/token");
    httpService.setMethod("POST");
    httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpService.addParam(type="body", value="client_id=#application.clientID#&client_secret=#application.clientsecretID#&grant_type=#application.grant_type#");
    result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
    return this;
}
```

problem how can i use the token returned by the method in other methods, if i dump the `init`, i am just getting the functions, how can i use the data returned by the http

just not getting in my head, because the token is alive for 3600

Thanks

Comment: If you se the result to `this.result = http...` then the data will be visible outside of the function.

Comment: Eek hang-on though @JamesAMohler. That exposes the value to the outside world asd well, which one would seldom want to do. Probably just the variables scope would be the correct answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James says, you should store the result of the http call as an instance variable. Here's one way of doing it <s>using a `property` and specifying `accessors=true` for the component so that you can call `setHttpResult()` and `getHttpResult()` without having to write those methods.</s> using the `variables` scope which will make it available to other methods within the component, but not outside.

```
/* Test.cfc */
component name="test"{

    property name="httpResult" type="struct";

    public any function init(){
        //use "var" to ensure the variable is local to the function only
        var httpService = new http();
        httpService.setUrl("#Application.baseURL#security/oauth2/token");
        httpService.setMethod("POST");
        httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpService.addParam(type="body", value="client_id=#application.clientID#&client_secret=#application.clientsecretID#&grant_type=#application.grant_type#");
        //store the result privately in the instance
        variables.httpResult = httpService.send().getPrefix();
        return this;
    }

    public void function someOtherMethod(){
        // this method can access the result struct
        var returnedContent = variables.httpResult.fileContent;
    }


}
```

<s>You can then use `getHttpResult()` inside or outside your component. For example from an external script:</s>

```
test = New test(); // calls the init() method
WriteDump( test.getHttpResult() ); //auto-generated "getter"
```

Comment: Don't think this is a great answer when the Q was just to expose the value to other methods... no need to expose it to the outside world. Also... there's a good chance the getter / setter(!!!? Why would you advocate creating a public setter for this?) is gonna be pretty anti-pattern-ish (re https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). At the very least, things should not be exposed publicly until they are *explicitly needed*, which is not the case here. Just *put it in the variables scope* is the answer here.

Comment: Fair cop, Adam. Didn't think through my answer. Have tried to improve it. I personally like `properties` for documenting instance vars, but you're right access should be private until needed.